# Get parent widget by object name

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

How do I get a parent object by its name? `QWidget::parentWidget()` goes only one level up; I rather need a recursive search equivalent to `QObject::findChild()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QWidget` inherits `QObject` so `QObject::objectName` is available to all `QWidgets`

You can recurse up the parent tree by creating a free function somewhat like the following (note this is untested code)

```
QWidget* parentByName(QWidget* widget, QString name)
{
    widget = parentWidget();
    if (widget && widget->objectName() != name)
        return parentByName(widget, name);
    return widget;
}
```

This will return either the widget you're looking for, or a nullptr in the event it can't be found

Comment: So I am right saying there's no implemented function for this purpose?

Comment: That's a question best directed at [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget-members.html) - search for "parent" and see what you find

Comment: in the first snippet, did you mean `return parent->parentByName(name);` for the recursive call? otherwise you are just calling the same function with the same parameter until stack overflow

Comment: @tobi303 yes, you're right - in fact it wouldn't work because it would require all `QWidgets` to have `parentByName`, which the don't - I'm going to remove the first option